# Check if cookie exists and hide content

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

**EDIT:**this works (gives me an alert):

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("TR_LNG") >= 0) { alert('cookie found'); }
```

So it's the hiding mechanism thats the problem.
BUT in console: `$('.langselmain').hide('fast');` this works as well so i have no idea wtf is wrong. **END EDIT**

I'm trying to check for a language preference cookie, and if it exists to hide the language selection dialogue. this is what I'm using to check the cookie:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("TR_LNG") >= 0) { $('.langselmain').hide('fast'); }
```

and the content to hide:

```
<div id="langselectsplash" class="langselectsplash langselmain"><div id="select"><img src="http://sarvatma.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/sarvalogo2.png" /><p> 
        <style>#tr_setdeflang{display:none;}</style><div class="no_translate transposh_flags" ><a id="en" href="/about/" class="tr_active">English</a><a id="fr" href="/fr/about/">Français</a><a id="de" href="/de/about/">Deutsch</a><a id="ja" href="/ja/about/">日本語</a><a id="pl" href="/pl/about/">Polski</a><a id="es" href="/es/about/">Español</a></div>        </p></div></div><div id="langsplashfade" class="langselmain"></div>
```

and its just not working

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Does the following alert work? `if (document.cookie.indexOf("TR_LNG") >= 0) { alert('cookie found'); }`

Comment: is there no way to do it without the plugin? also, surprisingly, the alert works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

js to set the cookie:

```
$.cookie('TR_LNG', 'set the value');
```

js to hide:

```
if ($.cookie('TR_LNG')) {
    $('.langselmain').hide();
}
```

Working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ypED/1/

Edit: no plugin  http://jsfiddle.net/3ypED/4/

Comment: is there no way to do it without a plugin?

Comment: actually it looks like the cookie detection part works perfect because this works if (document.cookie.indexOf("TR_LNG") >= 0) { alert('cookie found'); } in that it gives me an lert, so its the hiding mechanism thats failing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check cookie exist or not by

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("Login_ID") < 0) {
}
```

`document.cookie.indexOf("Login_ID") = -1` means cookie expired
`document.cookie.indexOf("Login_ID") = 0` means cookie found

Answer (score 0):

ugh it was a stupid mistake.
I didnt bind my function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//that code
});
```

fixed it.